# prime generator in python up to 20

Tags: python, primes

I don't understand why this (python) code does not produces the primes between 1 and 20.

```
P = [2, 3]
p = 4
N = list(range(2, p))
M = list(range(1, p))
while True:
    for n in N:
        if p / n in M:
            p += 1
            if p == 20:
                print(P)
                break
        else:
            P.append(p)
            p += 1
            if p == 20:
                print(P)
                break
```

The idea was to start with 4 and check if division between the number and another (smaller) is a hole number, if it is, put it in a list and in the end print the list.

instead of printing the primes it printed. 
[2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

I know this is a very unproductive way of finding primes but I still don't understand why this is not working.

Thanks and sorry for  my English.

Comment: instead of printing the primes it printed. <- ?

Comment: You should give your variables better names. You have both `p` and `P` as variables in your code, making it needlessly difficult to read.

Comment: You are not exiting the first loop, it will loop infinitely

Comment: I forgot to say, instead of printing the primes it printed:
[2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a Python generator function to get the primes you can do the following

```
def getPrimes(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if(len([j for j in range(2,i-1) if i%j==0]) == 0):
            yield i

n = 20
[i for i in getPrimes(n)]
```

> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]

---

A Python generator function without the list comprehension for your convenience

```
def getPrimes(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if i < 3: yield i
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0: break
            if j == i - 1: yield i
```

---

Using a simple for loop

```
n = 20
primes = []
for i in range(2, n):
    if i < 3: primes.append(i)
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0: break
        if j == i-1: primes.append(i)

primes
```

> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]

---

Using a loop with a list comprehension

```
n = 20
primes = []
for i in range(2, n):
    if i < 3: primes.append(i)
    elif len([j for j in range(2,i) if i%j==0]) == 0:
        primes.append(i)

primes
```

> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]

Answer (score 1):

You are not exiting the first loop which will cause infinite looping. However, if you want an efficient way of producing primes in a range you should have a look at [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Here is an example:

```
primes = []
allPrimes = []

def sieve(n):
    global primes, allPrimes
    primes = [True]*(n+1)
    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    i = 2
    while i*i <= n:
        if primes[i]:
            j = i*i
            while j <= n:
                primes[j] = False
                j += i
        i += 1
    allPrimes = [i for i in range(len(primes)) if primes[i]]

sieve(20)
print(allPrimes)
```

output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Basically, we get primes by eliminating composite numbers (non primes).

Comment: Why am I not exiting the first loop when `p` is 20? and why does it stops if I don't exit the loop?

also, I know there are better ways of generating primes, I just don't understand why this way doesn't work.

Comment: You are breaking the inner loop when you break and not the outer one.